# tcp error code 10060 calling WCF Service

Tags: windows, wcf, service, tcp

I have a windows service that is making a call out to an IIS hosted WCF on the same server.  This worked fine up until our virtual server crashed and had to be rebuilt.  Ever since then I have been getting a "tcp error code 10060" error when the windows service tries to call this WCF service.

The IP that it gives does not exist, it is an old IP address.  The IP address is not specified anywhere in code or in a config file.  I can launch the WCF service from IE from that machine and any other machine that I call it from.  I am told that DNS is fine.

Is there something else that I am missing somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a DNS issue where we had 2 entries in DNS.